# Garbage Values concatenated with table name in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Whenever I want to get db table name from Entity Framework it concatenates Garbage value with it.

It only happens whenever I try to *delete* any entity

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not table name. Its name of entity type. You have lazy-loading enabled, so you see the dynamic proxy class name. If you'll turn off proxy generation, then you'll see expected type name:

```
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

But I would not recommend treat this information as table name, because entity can be mapped to any table, which does not have same name as entity type.

Comment: But it's giving exact table name on State.Added and State.Modified, you meant I must disable lazy-loading here?

Comment: @ShahAbdullah because proxy is generated when you have entity returned from database. Proxy is used to lazy-load related entities. When you add new entity, you create instance of ordinal entity type

Comment: Working Fine but can I globally initialize db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; instead of going to HTTPOST of Delete Controllers?

Comment: @ShahAbdullah you can leave lazy-loading enabled. Just prettify entity name (you can use substring till first underscore symbol) and don't treat it as table name - that's a different thing.

Comment: Substring stuff sounds more logical Brother Thank You !!